# PHP, MYSQL: print a DB field based on the result of two other DB fields

Tags: php, mysql, select

I need to select two fields from a table in my database, if the two fields aren't empty then I would need to select a new field from the database and print that out into a div class on my page.

I have managed to create a function which should call the two initial fields from my table however cannot figure out how to do the rest.

```
function returnPlanMoon($val,$con)
{
    return (mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Planet, Moon From MK1 WHERE id = 1"));
}
```

Eventually I want to be able to check the two initial results and based on the answer select a specific field in the database to be printed.

Comment: Not quite sure where the problem is, correct me if I don't understand. 

1. Query database for `Planet` and `Moon`.
2. If these values exists for `{$val}`, run another query.
3. Print the result.

What's the question? "When the user clicks on a button" is usually a form being submitted, which calls the script.

Do you want to display the above result on the page that has the form being submitted?

Comment: @AndrewBreksa sorry I think adding the bottom section might have confused my question. However yes I want to run two queries, if the values exist then run another query and finally print the value found from the second query. And This would need to run as the page loads on a submit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object, which has a num_rows property. Simply check that `$result->num_rows` is greater than 0, then run the subsequent query. Depending on the query being run, you might be able to join the queries and skip the second query.

If a result is returned, but either `Planet` or `Moon` is/can be empty (null/empty string), you'll need to pull those values from the result and check each one via [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if(!empty($row['Planet'] and !empty($row['Moon'])){
     //run query here, grab Planet and Moon from $row:
     //mysqli_query($conn, "select foo from bar where Planet={$row['Planet']} and Moon={$row['Moon']}");
    }
}
```

Comment: My only issue with using num_rows is that is doesn't check the contents itself. My objective is to check the results from the initial query and depending on those results search for a specifc query and print that. 

For instance if query A == 1 and query B == 2 then query C == 3 however if query A == 2 and query B == 3 then query C == 5 and so on...

Comment: @C.Marks What's the second query? A more specific example will help me give you a better (more specific) answer.

Comment: Breska sorry let me try and explain properly, for what I am trying to create there are eight individual 'planets' which each have six 'moons', when the user has clicked onto a 'planet' and a 'moon' the DB is updated. A query is run to find out what the 'planet' and 'moon' columns in the DB now contain, based on those results a third query is run to fill a description box with specific information relating to the ‘planet’ and ‘moon’.

If the planet == RM and the moon == 1 then the third query is for 'RM1', if the planet == TM and the moon == 2 then the third query is for 'TM2'

Comment: @C.Marks What's an example of the query you run to get the description?

Comment: I dont know the php format for the if/condition statement to check however if the initial query...

function returnPlanMoon($val,$con)
{
    return (mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Planet, Moon From MK1 WHERE id = {$val}"));
}

returns Planet as 'Rm' and Moon as '1' then the query for the description would be..

function returnRm1($val,$con)
{
    return (mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Desc From DescTable WHERE id = 1"));
}

The only way I can see it working is to have multiple if statements in a seperate document for now and once its all working try and use generated statements.

Comment: @C.Marks Doesn't seem like you need to check, if `MK1.Moon` to `DescTable.id` is one-to-one:
`$moonId = $row['Moon'];`
`mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Desc From DescTable WHERE id = {$moonId}"));`

Comment: How would i then check the second condition against that however, the Planet?

Comment: Is there a `Planet` field in the `DescTable` table? If so, then add another `where` condition for that planet as with `id` for `Moon`.

Comment: Okay I think I now know what I can do, thank you very much for all of your help, its been frustrating me for a little which now!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnPlanMoon($val,$con){

    $result (mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Planet, Moon From MK1 WHERE id = $val"));

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($num_rows > 0){
       // select a new field from the database and print that out into a div class on my page.
    }

}
```